# Hash navigation problem while using jquery mobile with asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am looking to standardize the processing of ajax #anchors at the server side, using MVC.

Before a controller action is invoked I want to convert every request with ajax anchors into a request without ajax anchors, so that the controller code does not know there were anchors in the request:

For example:

1) /user/profile#user/photos should be treated as /user/photos

2) /main/index#user/profile/33 should be treated as /user/profile/33

What is the best technique in MVC to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

This should necessarily be done on the client side, probably using jquery as everything that follows the `#` sign is never sent to the server.

Comment: can you tell me tell me how? Because I am relatively new to this?

Comment: This will largely depend on your scenario. How are the requests performed? Are you using forms, actionlinks, ...

Answer (score 0):

I too struggle with same issue and I solved this problem after looking at Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview template code. I added following code in my _layout.cshtml, please note we must load jquery.mobile*.js file **after** following script tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
              // As of Beta 2, jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
              // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page, or when clicking "back"
              // after a form post), hence disabling it. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/api/globalconfig.html
              @{
                  if (ViewBag.JqueryMobileAjaxEnabled != null && ViewBag.JqueryMobileAjaxEnabled == true)
                  {
                    @: $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    @: $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
                  }
              }
          });
        </script>
     **<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>**
```